# Firebird Database & Linux Red Hat Base Server for FireBird Database

Tags: sql, linux, firebird

Kindly give your comments / input ...

We are considering Firebird Database, and getting a Linux Red Hat Server for our Database System .. is it advisable?,

What's the future like for Linux and Firebird Database?

---

Also, are there many developers available with knowledge of Firebird?

Answer (score 2):

i'm using FirebirdSQL as database for a software i wrote (db is 100Mb, 50 tables up to 65000rows, 20 views, 30 triggers). 
i found it very stable and fast as mysql, at least on windows.

i found very usefull the hot backup anche the incremental backup.

I never tried on any unix, but i think that postgresql or mysql should be more mature.

Answer (score 2):

Firebird is included in Redhat Enterprise or at least you have a repository supported by Firebird consultants (ibphoenix)

I have tested it on Fedora core 11 and Centos 5.3 (community version for redhat enterprise)

http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=2807

another hint for you is that firebird stable is included in Ubuntu , Debian and Opensuse

So the community it's growing larger , it's still a long way to reach mysql level but with small steps who knows we might replace the LAMP with Firebird + Ubuntu+ Nginx +Php

Answer (score 1):

"...the design emphasis for Firebird seems to be on small, fast and minimum management. This is ideal for developers who need a database for storage, but do not want to spend too much time on tuning the database for performance. In many situations you may not even need stored procedures, or do complex table joins. In such cases, Firebird is the ideal compromise between size and functionality."

> [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php) is a relational database
>   offering many ANSI SQL standard
>   features that runs on Linux, Windows,
>   and a variety of Unix platforms.
>   Firebird offers excellent concurrency,
>   high performance, and powerful
>   language support for stored procedures
>   and triggers. It has been used in
>   production systems, under a variety of
>   names, since 1981.

See this links

[Firebird Database on Linux](http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/firebird102.html)

[Linux Journal - Introduction to the Firebird Database](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7010)

[Firebird embedded on Linux HOWTO](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/Firebird-Embedded-Linux-HOWTO.html)

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

The main web site for [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) shows current development activity, with multiple releases in preparation.  The product has a moderately long and slightly checkered history, being derived from Interbase.  AFAICT, it is a decent system - it has longevity enough to support that.

I doubt that there are all that many people who specialize in Firebird, certainly compared to, say, MySQL or MS SQL Server, or ...  However, I don't think there is anything in Firebird that would be hard for someone who knows one of the mainstream SQL DBMS (commercial or open source) to learn.  You'd be looking for a someone with good foundational knowledge of database management and a flexible mindset (knowledge of Firebird a bonus) rather than someone who knows all the details of every version of Firebird ever.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird is a great database and recently won [Best project for enterprise](http://sourceforge.net/community/cca09/) at Sourceforge Community Choice Awards.

I use it as the main database for the software I made: Firebird is a rock.

This software is installed on many of my customers (more than 250 customers) but only on Microsoft systems.